# Gson from Object To Object

Tags: json, object, gson

I'm trying to do a json converter of a map with a generic Object.
assuming you have the following example:

```
class MyClass1
{
    String v1;
    Boolean v2;
}

class MyClass2
{
   Integer v3;
   String v4;
}

class MyContainer
{
     Map<String, Object>lst;

    MyContainer() {
        lst = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
}


    public  main() {
        MyContainer  c1, c2;
        Gson g = new Gson();

        c1 = new MyContainer();
        MyClass1 my1 = new MyClass1();
        MyClass2 my2 = new MyClass2();
        my1.v1 = "v1";
        my1.v2 = true;
        my2.v3 = 10;
        my2.v4="v4";

        c1.lst.put("MyClass1", my1);
        c1.lst.put("MyClass2", my2);

        String json = g.toJson(c1);
        c2 = g.fromJson(json, MyContainer.class);
```

When I use g.ToJson i have the good json result but, when i call g.fromJson it obviously doesn't convert well because it cannot understand which class must be use in order to map the input json.
Infact, the c2.lst.get("MyClass1") does not return an instance of MyClass1 but a com.google.gson.internal.StringMap